# javax.swing.JDialog freezes when it loss focus?

Tags: java, swing, freeze

I'm writing a application using Swing. I have my main application frame (`javax.swing.JFrame`) which can open a my 1st `javax.swing.JDialog`, called `ClientMngDialog` which contains a `javax.swing.JTable` filled with data loaded from my database.

When the I select a client in the table, I want to open a 2nd `javax.swing.JDialog`, named `ClientEditDialog` on top of the 1st one, and then I can edit the informations of the selected client.

Both `javax.swing.JDialog` use `Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL`, since Javadoc says :

*A document-modal dialog box blocks all windows from the same document, except windows from its child hierarchy. In this context, a document is a hierarchy of windows that share a common ancestor, called the document root, which is the closest ancestor window without an owner.*

The 1st dialog works fine, nothing weired happend. But the 2nd one, which is over the 1st one, **freezes** when I click somewhere else outside the dialog (*maybe I can consider it as a loss of focus*). All the components on it don't respond anymore, and the only thing I can do is clicking its close button.

I've tried the `Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL`, doesn't help, always the same problem. I have put `SwingUtilites.isEventDispatchThread()` everywhere, and it returns `true` as expected.

Anybody has a clue please ?

p.s. I'm using Debian Wheezy with Xfce 4 Desktop.

Comment: After rebooting my computer, the problem has just disappeared. Really weired, I don't know why. I will keep testing.

Comment: To be clear: when you're creating the `JDialog`, are you passing a reference to the parent window? Eg: `JDialog ClientEditDialog = new JDialog(this);` (from within a method of the JFrame)?

Comment: @BrianS Yes, kind of, my main frame has a singleton, since I always need its reference. So when I create the 1st dialog, I just call the singleton and retrieve the reference of the main frame. To create the 2nd dialog, yes, I just pass the `this` (reference to the 1st dialog) to the 2nd dialog.

Comment: Good Question, @BrianS - this leads to the solution: your second Dialog need the first dialog as Parent!

Comment: @MartinFrank It's already done, when I create my 2nd dialog, it has the reference to the 1st dialog as its parent. The problem disappeared after rebooting my PC, really weired.

Comment: Hello @vesontio, i'm glad that this problem solved itself ^^

Comment: @Martin Frank, Yeah me too ^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after rebooting my computing. Really weired, and I don't know why.